# Hide 1 row above and 8 rows below a cell which changes based on picklist from another sheet

Tags: loops, excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to automate a reporting form. Text values selected from from a validation dropdown list on Sheet1 designate (by way of formulae) whether or not cells on Sheet9 have a value of "" or a concatenated hybrid of values entered on the first sheet.

Sheet9 basically contains 200 blank tables (including rows in between, 9 rows per table) and the cells we are concerned with give each table a title to signify that they need to be completed. Any table without a title present should be hidden.

I have named a Range "JanRange" which is just the title cells, I was hoping to loop to each target title cell, evaluate whether or not it is displaying a value and if not, hide the block of rows from 1 row above to 8 rows below.

I've looked all over the place but anything I try to run doesn't seem to work (I think the main problem I've had is getting the code for Sheet9 to run based on the cell on Sheet9 changing via a formula dependent on a change from Sheet1)

If you need me to provide more detail, please just ask!

Many thanks,

DuNk

**EDIT:**

So I've now got the following code which will successfully hide the row of each title cell in my named range:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Cell As Range
   For Each Cell In Range("TestRange")
      If Cell.Value = "" Then
      Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Else: Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
   Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Which is great! But I need to extend what is hidden to the block of nine rows (1 above and 8 below) rather than just the single row. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Just tried the code below but am getting a runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error..

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("TestRange")
        If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(8, 0).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: cell.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(8, 0).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Okay I think I've got there with the following:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngMyRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
            Dim x As Integer
            Dim y As Integer
    Set rngMyRange = Range("TestRange")
    For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
        If cell.Value = "" Then
                                    x = cell.Row - 1
                                    y = cell.Row + 6
            Rows("" & x & ":" & "" & y & "").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else:                       x = cell.Row - 1
                                    y = cell.Row + 6
            Rows("" & x & ":" & "" & y & "").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It doesn't work with Worksheet_calculate() for some reason but being as data entry is on a different tab, going with Worksheet_activate() works just fine :)

**EDIT:**

**Okay having now got this into my full workbook rather than the small scale test version, having the code running on 200 cells in JanRange is taking somewhere in the region of 10 seconds. There's no way I want this stuck to Worksheet_calculate or even worksheet_activate. I've tried associating it to a form control button on Sheet1 but it doesn't work..**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you need is:

1. To automatically catch changes in Sheet1
2. To automatically hide cells in a second worksheet based on this change

Therefore:
1. Add the worksheet changed method to Sheet1 in VBA
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx
2. In the mentioned method simply hide cells using e.g.

```
Range("1:10").EntireRow.Hidden = true
```

This code will hide rows 1-10.

The setback of using the worksheet change method is (as I recall) that you will not be able to use the undo function (CTRL+Z)

Comment: Hi Tkacprow, thanks for your comment! The issue with that is doing it that way would mean individually specifying 200 different ranges which will be seriously time consuming, I was hoping there would be a way I could loop through the JanRange (table title cells) and hide the rows 1 above and 8 below relative to the cell address of each cell in the range.